# My code is fine and i can still deploy on Netlify but my previous deployments on Vercel can't be reached

Tags: next.js, vercel

I honestly have no idea why I can't connect to my web app on Vercel. It's a NextJS 14 app with server functions, deployments are from the main branch and the site was working until 2 hours ago. I deployed on Netlify with the exact same configurations (not much, just env variables) and it works fine. Runtime logs show no error on Vercel either.
This is my first time deploying any project. There isn't much error information i can provide, any browser I try shows:
"This site can’t be reached
took too long to respond.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_TIMED_OUT"

I deployed my app a week ago and committed a lot of changes to the main branch during this time. Today, out of nowhere I can't reach the vercel.app domain.